# JSF - ternary operator in value attribute

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

Is it possible to put a ternary operator to have a condition in a "value" attribute of a JSF tag ? And moreover is it possible in a datatable tag to have something like this :

```
<h:dataTable id="table" value="#{myBean.choice ? myBean.listOne : myBean.listTwo}"
                        var="item" > 
                 . . .
```

Comment: why not? Your listOne and listTwo should be list of same type. Other question if it effective to use EL in that place.

Comment: Why don't you just run you app and get to know?

Comment: @Vasil my two list are actually of the same type and I want use this syntaxe I want to use that because I would like to display different list in the datatable depending on the page, if it's in editing or reading mode

Comment: @SRy I asked to know the best and most efficient way to do what I want to have on my page

Comment: It depends on the case of use. Are you going to frequently switch between one list and the other one? Keep in mind your posted code will keep both lists in memory (at least if you use `@ViewScoped`). Other choice is just to use a List and clear/load elements when switching to *edit* mode.