# HTML: Change Tag-Attribut "value"

Tags: jsf, el

I am trying to change the value-attribute within a primefaces-dataTable tag. My web-application has different user-roles. I am able to get the current logged in user-role. Now I need to adjust the `<p:dataTabe>` to get the table filled with user-role based data. Below my html-tag:

```
<p:dataTable id="parentTable" var="parent" value="#{parentController.inactiveParents}">
```

What I want is to change the `value="#{parentController.inactiveParents}"` to `value="#{parentController.parents}"`.

Is it possible to include an if-block or something like that and how would it look like?

I already tried to insert a `<script>`-tag but the compiler says the `<p:dataTable>`-tag is not closed.

**SOLUTION:**

`<p:dataTable id="parentTable" var="parent" value="#{sessionInfoBean.hasRole('ADMIN') ? parentController.parents : parentController.inactiveParents}">`

Comment: You could by using the ternary operatior. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382466/jsf-ternary-operator-in-value-attribute

Comment: thx. it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be more organized and best-practice to have
    value="#{parentController.inactiveParents}"
and have the method ParentController.getInactiveParents() handle the user role logic in the backing bean?
It's a good idea to avoid writing this kind of logic in html, as it's tough to debug.